# Subclass multiprocessing.Process but don't invoke the __init__ method of multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I know `multiprocessing.Process` is analogous to `threading.Thread` and when I subclass `multiprocessing.Process` to create a process, I find that I don't have to invoke the `__init__()` method of the parent class. I have wrote a few test scripts and find some problems:

- The **_parent_pid** variable is initialized in the `__init__` method of `multiprocessing.Process`. However, if I don't invoke the init method of `Process`, I still could use this variable in the subclass.
  I don't know why because in my opinion, if subclassing a parent class, the subclass could only get the methods of the parent but not the variables of the parent if the subclass don't call the init method in the parent class.
- Why does the subclass of `threading.Thread` have to call the init method in the parent class before doing other things while the subclass of `multiprocessing.Process` not? I have read the source code of the both classes and think that it may be a reason that threads in Python have to use some synchronous mechanism under the hood while processes not.

The first script is part of the demonstration of the first problem and the second script is related to the two problems:

Script #1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = 'parent'

    def myprint(self):
        print('Hi')


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.myprint()

    def print_parent(self):
        try:
            print(self.parent)
        except Exception:
            print('No such a variable self.parent.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child = Child()
    child.print_parent()
```

Script #2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import time
import multiprocessing

class Test(multiprocessing.Process):

    # def __init__(self):
    #     super(Test, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('process: %s, pid: %d, ppid: %d' % (self.name, self.pid, self._parent_pid))
            time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    for i in xrange(3):
        process = Test()
        process.start()

    print('My pid is %d' % (os.getpid(),))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a subclass doesn't define `__init__()` at all, the parent class `__init__()` is invoked - same as for any other method.  Your `Test` class does not define `__init__()`, so when you construct a `Test` instance, `multiprocessing.Process`'s (the parent class's) `__init__()` is invoked.

Your `Parent/Child` example is very different:  there `Child.__init__()` **is** defined.

The same is true of `threading.Thread` subclasses (or any other subclasses of any other class).  If a subclass doesn't define `__init__()` at all, then `threading.Thread.__init__()` is invoked.  Indeed, I've routinely relied on that for years :-)

You *need* to call a parent class `__init__()` only if a subclass *does* define its own `__init__()`.

Comment: Oh, yes! The two problems are caused by my incomplete understanding of class initialization in Python. Thank you very much!

Comment: The main take-home point ;-) is that there's nothing special about `__init__()` here:  it follows the same rules (in these respects) as all class methods.

Comment: Does it mean that when creating an instance of a class, the Python interpreter first creates the class instance, and then tries to invoke the init method in the class and if there's not an init method, then it will search for it in the parent class and try to invoke it?

Comment: In the case of single inheritance, that's a good enough understanding.  In general, it follows the class's MRO ([Method Resolution Order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) )and invokes `__init__()` on the first class in the MRO that *has* an `__init__`.  At least for "new style" class (in Python 2), that always succeeds, because every class eventually traces back to the `object` class.  And all invocations of all methods (not just `__init__`) follow the MRO.

Comment: It's a little hard to understand MRO...but thanks again for your help and the reference could be good material for me to dive into Python :)

Comment: Multiple inheritance can be confusing in any language - it's inherently complex.  And OO languages were around for decades before the specific MRO scheme used by Python was created:  it took a long time even for language designers to figure out what was really important in an MRO.  I think your "a little hard" is a severe understatement ;-)